# Airflow integration with AWS development machine to access admin UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, airflow

I am trying to use Airflow for workflow management on my development machine on aws. I have multiple virtual environments setup and have installed airflow. 
I am listening to port 8080 in my nginx conf as:

```
listen private.ip:8080;
```

I have allowed inbound connection to port 8080 on my AWS machine.

I am unable to access my airflow console as well as admin page from my public ip / website address.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a tunnel for viewing UI locally.

```
ssh -N -L 8080:ec2-machineip-compute-x.amazonaws.com:8080 YOUR_USERNAME_FOR_MACHINE@ec2-machineip-compute-x.amazonaws.com:8080
```

> ssh -N -L 8080:ec2-machineip-compute-x.amazonaws.com:8080 YOUR_USERNAME_FOR_MACHINE@ec2-machineip-compute-x.amazonaws.com:8080
>
> localhost:8080 for viewing airflow 8080 UI